# After filtering I am unable to find the minimum value in the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, minimum

I am trying to find the minimum Total Charges for the Los Angeles City from my data frame, I have attached the screenshot of my data frame [City and Total Charges would be visible in my dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRMk5.png), So I have already tried few things but nothing worked.

[image]

Here is the code which I used where tcc is my dataset:

```py
lacity = tcc[tcc["City"] == "Los Angeles"]
lacity[lacity.tcc["Total Charges"] == lacity.tcc["Total Charges"].min()
```

When I filter with Los Angeles it is working fine, but when I am trying to filter it with minimum total charges, it is giving me an error

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tcc'

Comment: In the second variable assignment you are invoking `lacity.tcc['Total Charges']` and it is not correct. `lacity` is a separate dataset from `tcc` one. You should use `lacity[lacity['Total Charges'] == lacity['Total Charges'].min()`.

Comment: Oh Yeah, it worked. Got it, I will keep this in mind. Thank you very much!